# Laravel's blade can't output HTML

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want Blade to output a little FontAwesome icon when the verified attribute is set to true, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
{!! $job->verfied ? '<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>' : '' !!}
```

Can anyone please give the correct syntax?

Comment: Define what "doesn't seem to work" means, please. Check the spelling of `verfied`, for starters.

Comment: That should be correct. Look at the source in the browser and see what is being output. Also, are you sure the spelling isn't `verified` and not `verfied`?

Comment: @ceejayoz How silly, I thought I wrote it correctly thank you.

Comment: @BounasserAbdelwahab Heh, there you go. If you're having trouble with a conditional, *always* start with outputting the results of the conditional (using something like Laravel's `dd`, or `var_dump`) to make sure they're what you expect them to be.

Answer (score 2):

You can use @if directive

```
@if($job->verified)
<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the `verified` attribute.

```
{!! $job->verified ? '<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>' : '' !!}
```